# Objective C - NSArray's indexOfObject: not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I use `[items indexOfObject:items.lastObject]` to get the last index, but this code returns `nil`. Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: It's not returning `nil`. It's returning `0` meaning that it's matching on the 1st object (index 0) in the array. Do `po items.firstObject`. Is it also a fixed space bar button item?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, first element and the last element are fixedspaces, but all elements are reference types. The comparison between reference types should be the comparison of memory addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and last object in your array are both bar button items created with the system item of "fixed space".

The result of calling `indexOfObject:` is `0`, not `nil`. This means that the object is being found at index `0`. `indexOfObject:` can't return `nil`. If an object isn't found, it returns the special value `NSNotFound` which is the unsigned value for `-1`.

From the documentation for `indexOfObject:`:

> Starting at index `0`, each element of the array is passed as an argument to an `isEqual:` message sent to anObject until a match is found or the end of the array is reached. Objects are considered equal if `isEqual:` (declared in the `NSObject` protocol) returns `YES`.

The implementation of `UIBarButtonItem isEqual:` will return `YES` if two bar button item instances are created with the same system item (and probably a few other properties as well).

`indexOfObject:` is not based on the instance of the object, it's based on `isEqual:`.

If you want to find the index of an object based on the identity (its address) of the object instead of `isEqual:`, use `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:`.

```
p [items indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:items.lastObject]
```

will give you `6` instead of `0`.